# Dropdown reloading in AMP list

Tags: jquery, mustache, amp-html, amp-list

I am trying dynamic dropdowns in AMP I am able to get the output but one of the dropdowns is getting refreshed for some reason. As I am new to mustache and AMP i am not able to figure it out.

Below is the link for the output: https://capellaamp.herokuapp.com/

Partial code:

```
<amp-list width="auto" height="25" layout="fixed-height" src="https://capellaamp.herokuapp.com/dropdown.json">
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        <select on="
            change:
              AMP.setState({
                test: dropdown.items[0].countries.filter(x => x.name == event.value)[0]
              })">
          <option value="">Choose Degree</option>
          {{#countries}}
          <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
          {{/countries}}
        </select>
      </template>
    </amp-list>
    <amp-list width="auto" height="25" layout="fixed-height" [src]="test || 'https://capellaamp.herokuapp.com/dropdown.json'" src="https://capellaamp.herokuapp.com/dropdown.json">
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        <select on="
            change:
              AMP.setState({
                test1: test.cities.filter(x => x.name == event.value)[0]
              })">
          <option value="">Choose AOS</option>
          {{#cities}}
          <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
          {{/cities}}
        </select>
      </template>
    </amp-list>
    <amp-list width="auto" height="25" layout="fixed-height" [src]="test1 || 'https://capellaamp.herokuapp.com/dropdown.json'" src="https://capellaamp.herokuapp.com/dropdown.json">
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        <select>
          <option value="">Choose Specialization</option>
          {{#cities}}
          <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
          {{/cities}}
        </select>
      </template>
    </amp-list>
    <amp-state id="dropdown" src="https://capellaamp.herokuapp.com/dropdown.json"></amp-state>
```

Example taken from below link:
https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fadvanced%2Flinked_dropdowns%2Fsource%2F&mode=Responsive

Comment: What do you mean getting refreshed? looks fine to me

Comment: Second drop-down selects first option which default always

Comment: I am trying to have it work. if it didn't work we can raise an issue

Comment: bro your dyno has gone down. can you please make it up again

Comment: Actually I am trying a different way now, which works

Comment: But i see multiple request going in

Comment: Also the dropdown are getting hidden and show on selection